# Delta epsilon proof of convergence for $a_n = \frac{2-2n}{(n^2+n)(n^2-3)}$

Tags: calculus, epsilon-delta

> Let $a_n = \frac{2-2n}{(n^2+n)(n^2-3)}$. By definition, prove that $\{a_n\}$ converges.

So far what I have is;
Let $\varepsilon > 0$ and if $n>N$, $L = 0$ and $a_n \rightarrow L$

Want to show:
For all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $N> 0$ such that if $n>N$, $|a_n-L|< \varepsilon$
However, I need help to start the question:

I started with $a_n < (2-2n)/(n^2-3)$ because $(n^2+n) > 0$ but this doesn't hold for some reason? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you must  guess the value of the limit and then make the delta epsilon proof

Comment: @RabieHdaib Maybe it is a bit hidden, but OP knows that the limit is equal to 0.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: For large $n$
$$
\left|
\frac{2-2n}{(n^2+n)(n^2-3)}
\right|<\frac1{n^2+n}<\frac1{n^2},
$$
leading to a simple calculation of $N$ depending on $\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that for $n\ge2$ we have  $$\bigg | \frac {2-2n}{(n^2+n)(n^2-3)}\bigg |<\bigg |\frac {2-2n}{n^2}\bigg |\le\\\bigg |\frac {2}{n^2}\bigg |+\bigg |\frac {2}{n}\bigg |\to 0+0=0$$